# universal logger name in python logging yaml config file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, configuration, yaml

Ok, so the situation is I need to use a yaml config file for logging.(don't ask - I just need it :) ). And when writing the 'loggers:' directive I would like to use one logger and to be able to fetch it from multiple modules in my app using `getLogger(__name__)`. I know how to do it if I use a normal python config file for logging, but I can't to find a way to do the same with a yaml file.
using python 2.7
So long story short, that's what I have(this is just a simplified example of my problem, not part of the actual application :) ):

```
#this is app.py
import logging.config
import yaml
import os

def init_logging():
    path = 'logging.yaml'
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config['logging'])
    main()


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    logger.debug("done!")


init_logging()
```

and here's the logging.yaml config file:

```
logging:
    version: 1
    formatters:
        brief:
            format: '%(message)s'
        default:
            format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s] %(message)s'
            datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    handlers:
        console:
            class: logging.StreamHandler
            level: DEBUG

    loggers:
        app:
            handlers: [console]
            level: DEBUG
```

So as is it is here - it works. the 'done!' message shows in the console.
But I want to be able to set in the config not some distinct logger (here I called it 'app') but a universal, like if it was in a .py config it'would be

```
"loggers": {
    "": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "DEBUG",
    },
}
```

and then I would be using `logging.getLogger(__name__)` in different modules and it would always use the one "" logger and show me the messages.
So is there a way to create a universal logger in yaml? like the "": in the python logging config?
I tried (), ~, null - those don't do the work.
Basically I need to be able to call loggers with any names I want and to get one specified logger.
And yep - I can create a root directive in the yaml and call it by using `logging.getLogger()`

Comment: So did you try `''` instead of `~` or `null`?

Comment: Yep - no luck with it either.

Comment: That seems strange as the YAML including `''` would result in the same structure as you give in Python. You should try to figure out the difference between the Python structure and the loaded YAML by dumping and inspecting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I found an answer (thanks to @flyx!).
I compared the original python dict config and the converted from yaml dict config and found out that logging automatically adds `disable_existing_loggers: False` to the python config. After that I added this line to the yaml and used '' in the loggers directive.. and it worked!
So the resulting yaml config is like:

```
..............
disable_existing_loggers: False

loggers:
    '':
        handlers: [console, sentry]
        level: DEBUG
        propagate: False
```

and now it works. Even if I create a logger like `logging.getLogger('something')` and logger 'something' is not in the config then the app will use the '' logger.

@Don Kirkby's answer won't work if the logger is defined in the begining of the file(before configurating it). But it works with no problem if the logger is defined after configuring logging. So it's a resolve for the code from my question but not an answer to the question - "So is there a way to create a universal logger in yaml? like the "": in the python logging config?" That's why I didn't pick it as an answer. But he's comment is totally legit :)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use a special logger called `root`, outside the list of other loggers.

I found this in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details):

> *root* - this will be the configuration for the root logger. Processing of the configuration will be as for any logger, except that the `propagate` setting will not be applicable.

Here's the configuration from your question changed to use the `root` key:

```
logging:
    version: 1
    formatters:
        brief:
            format: '%(message)s'
        default:
            format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s] %(message)s'
            datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    handlers:
        console:
            class: logging.StreamHandler
            level: DEBUG

    root:
        handlers: [console]
        level: WARN
    loggers:
        app:
            level: DEBUG
```

That configures `app` at the `DEBUG` level, and everything else at the `WARN` level.