# Python logging (YAML config): Universal logger's level is not applied

Tags: python, logging

I've defined a logger without a name in my YAML logging config following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47108808/3077492) answer as shown in below snippet (Refer `logging.yaml` for the complete config).

```yaml
    loggers:
      '':
        level: WARNING
        propagate: True
```

I'm trying to provide all modules calling `logging.getLogger(__name__)` with a logger where the log level is `WARNING` via this "global" logger. There are no handlers attached & the handler of the root logger will emit the log message (hence `propagate = True`). `main.py` output shows that `main.py` & `module_2.py` is not getting its logger from above "global" logger config. Instead it's getting a new logger with level `NOTSET = 0`. But as `module_1.py` is getting the named logger `my_logger`, it is functioning properly with correct log level.

Questions:

1. Is this approach of defining a "global" logger possible with YAML?
2. If yes, what am I missing here?

---

`Project structure`

[image: Project structure]

---

`logging.yaml`

```yaml
    version: 1
    disable_existing_loggers: False

    formatters:
      simple:
        format: '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s'
    
    handlers:
      console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        formatter: simple
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
    
    root:
      level: ERROR
      handlers: [console]
    
    loggers:
      '':
        level: WARNING
        propagate: True
    
      my_logger:
        level: INFO
        propagate: True
```

---

`parse_config.py` - Log config reader

```py
    import os
    import yaml
    
    class ParseConfig:
        @classmethod
        def get_logging_config(cls):
            logging_config = os.path.join('conf', 'logging.yaml')
            
            with open(logging_config, 'r') as f:
                return yaml.safe_load(f)
```

---

`module_1.py`

```py
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
    
    
    class Class1:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            print('-- Class 1 Output')
            print(f"Logger = '{logger.name}' | Level = {logger.level} | Effective level = {logger.getEffectiveLevel()} | Parent = {logger.parent.name}")
    
            logger.debug(f"DEBUG Class 1")
            logger.info(f"INFO Class 1")
            logger.warning(f"WARNING Class 1")
            logger.error(f"ERROR Class 1")
            logger.critical(f"CRITICAL Class 1")
```

---

`module_2.py`

```py
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    
    class Class2:
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            print('-- Class 2 Output')
            print(f"Logger = '{logger.name}' | Level = {logger.level} | Effective level = {logger.getEffectiveLevel()} | Parent = {logger.parent.name}")
    
            logger.debug(f"DEBUG Class 2")
            logger.info(f"INFO Class 2")
            logger.warning(f"WARNING Class 2")
            logger.error(f"ERROR Class 2")
            logger.critical(f"CRITICAL Class 2")
```

---

`main.py` - Main program

```py
    import logging
    import logging.config
    from parse_config import ParseConfig
    
    logging.config.dictConfig(ParseConfig.get_logging_config())
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    print('-- Main Output')
    print(f"Logger = '{logger.name}' | Level = {logger.level} | Effective level = {logger.getEffectiveLevel()} | Parent = {logger.parent.name}")
    
    logger.debug(f"DEBUG Main")
    logger.info(f"INFO Main")
    logger.warning(f"WARNING Main")
    logger.error(f"ERROR Main")
    logger.critical(f"CRITICAL Main")
    
    from module_1 import Class1
    from module_2 import Class2
    
    c1 = Class1()
    c2 = Class2()
```

---

`main.py` - Console output

```
    -- Main Output
    Logger = '__main__' | Level = 0 | Effective level = 40 | Parent = root
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,556 - ERROR - __main__ - <module>:14 - ERROR Main
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,556 - CRITICAL - __main__ - <module>:15 - CRITICAL Main
    -- Class 1 Output
    Logger = 'my_logger' | Level = 20 | Effective level = 20 | Parent = root
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,558 - INFO - my_logger - __init__:11 - INFO Class 1
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,559 - WARNING - my_logger - __init__:12 - WARNING Class 1
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,559 - ERROR - my_logger - __init__:13 - ERROR Class 1
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,559 - CRITICAL - my_logger - __init__:14 - CRITICAL Class 1
    -- Class 2 Output
    Logger = 'module_2' | Level = 0 | Effective level = 40 | Parent = root
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,560 - ERROR - module_2 - __init__:13 - ERROR Class 2
    2023-06-19 12:50:25,560 - CRITICAL - module_2 - __init__:14 - CRITICAL Class 2
```